# Stimulsoft - view multiple reports inside stiViewer

Tags: vb.net, reporting, stimulsoft

I am using `Stimulsoft` libraries to create reports (`StiReport` control) and then showing it inside a `StiViewer` control. the problem is when i assign multiple reports to the viewer, it does not refresh or display the contents but it works just fine if i only set 1 report to the viewer.

code for 1 report (works ok) :

```
Dim vw As Viewer.StiViewerControl = ReportViewer.StiViewerControl1
rpt.Render(True)

vw.Report = rpt
vw.Refresh()

ReportViewer.ShowDialog()
```

code for several reports (doesnt work) :

```
 Dim vw As Viewer.StiViewerControl = ReportViewer.StiViewerControl1

        For Each rpt As StiReport In reps
                rpt.Render(True)
                vw.Reports.Add(rpt)
        Next


        vw.Refresh()
        ReportViewer.ShowDialog()
```

keep in mind that i dont get any errors. it just simply does not display several reports inside one viewer.

any suggestions ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer. i had to merge all reports inside a single report.

here is the code :

```
Dim rps As List(Of StiReport)

Dim singleFile As New StiReport
singleFile.NeedsCompiling = False
singleFile.IsRendered = True

Dim newUnit As Units.StiUnit = Units.StiUnit.GetUnitFromReportUnit(singleFile.ReportUnit)
singleFile.RenderedPages.Clear()

For Each rpt As StiReport In rps
    For Each page As StiPage In rpt.CompiledReport.RenderedPages
        page.Report = singleFile
        page.NewGuid()
        Dim oldUnit As Units.StiUnit = Units.StiUnit.GetUnitFromReportUnit(rpt.ReportUnit)
        If (singleFile.ReportUnit <> rpt.ReportUnit) Then
            page.Convert(oldUnit, newUnit)
        End If
        singleFile.RenderedPages.Add(page)
    Next
Next


Dim vw As Viewer.StiViewerControl = ReportViewer.StiViewerControl1
vw.Report = singleFile
vw.Refresh()
ReportViewer.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: do you know how can i do it in asp.net (c#) for two stimul report ?